# JavaScript/TypeScript Get Neighboring/Sibling Value in Object

Tags: typescript

How to get *value* of `wood` if I have *value* of `fruit`? I don't know in which forest to look for.

```
let oranges,cherry,deep,apples,cedar,shallow

let tree = 
  mountainForest: {
    fruit:oranges
    wood:cherry
    root:deep
  },
  rainyForest: {
    fruit:apples
    wood:cedar
    root:shallow
 }
```

This is what I tried:

```
var result = 'someval'
Object.keys(someObj).forEach((key) => {
    // can't figure out this part
})
```

Comment: You need to look through both of them, you will need to know which holds the value of `wood` before you can get the corresponding `fruit` value of the same object.

Comment: thanks! so no more effiecient way than cycle through all?

Comment: Nope, the only way to know is to look through them and find which one has that value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when i have only the value of the child key

Here you go:

```
let someObj: any = {
    'somekey': 'someval'
}

let whatYouHave = 'someval'
Object.keys(someObj).forEach((key) => {
    if (someObj[key] == whatYouHave){
        console.log('found Key!', key); // somekey
    }
})
```